# How to change View3DOverlay.show_stats?

Tags: python

Documentation: [View3DOverlay.show_stats](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.View3DOverlay.html?highlight=statistics#bpy.types.View3DOverlay.show_stats).

The UI shows the following:

[image]

However when I run `bpy.data.screens['Layout'].overlay.show_stats`, there is an error: `AttributeError: 'Screen' object has no attribute 'overlay`.

Comment: Trying to change `bpy.data.screens['Layout'].overlay.grid_scale = 0.001` and hit the same issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Look at the type.**

Sometimes the tooltips can be screwy as shown in question the `overlay` is not a property of screen.

On the [bpy.types.View3DOverlay](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.View3DOverlay.html?highlight=statistics#bpy.types.View3DOverlay.show_stats) help page linked go to the bottom to **references**.

WIll see a link to [SpaceView3D.overlay](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.SpaceView3D.html#bpy.types.SpaceView3D.overlay)

which is the space assigned to the 3d view.

In the python console

```
>>> for i, a in enumerate(C.screen.areas):
...     i, a.type
...     
(0, 'PROPERTIES')
(1, 'CONSOLE')
(2, 'OUTLINER')
(3, 'VIEW_3D')

>>> 
>>> space = C.screen.areas[3].spaces.active
>>> space.overlay.show_stats
True

>>> type(space)
<class 'bpy.types.SpaceView3D'>

>>> type(space.overlay)
<class 'bpy.types.View3DOverlay'>
```

If a script is run within the context of the 3Dview area, a panel draw, menu shortcut etc, then

```
space = context.space_data
```

The blender screen is split into areas. When you change the area type in UI, the active space used is associated with that type.  When you see the type `SpaceFoo` you know its the space of the "Foo" area.  eg "SpaceProperties", "SpaceConsole"