# How to lock viewport to object via the Python API

Tags: python, animation, 3d-view

From the Blender UI there is the option of "Lock to Object" of the Viewport that can be seen in the following image. I wanted to ask how is it possible to enable this option via Python?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Property of the 3D view space**

Similarly to [Change tile grid shape](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/210824/change-tile-grid-shape/210826#210826) and similarly to the answer it was similar to.

Mousing over the property in UI (with developer extras enabled) shows the proprerty as

```
SpaceView3D.lock_object
```

Python console, lock 3d viewport area of screen to context object.

```
>>> for i, a in  enumerate(C.screen.areas):
...     i, a.type
...     
(0, 'PROPERTIES')
(1, 'CONSOLE')
(2, 'OUTLINER')
(3, 'VIEW_3D')

>>> space = C.screen.areas[3].spaces.active



>>> space.lock_object = C.object
>>> C.object
bpy.data.objects['Cube']

>>> space.lock_object
bpy.data.objects['Cube']

>>> type(space)
<class 'bpy.types.SpaceView3D'>
```

set to `None` to remove

```
space.lock_object = None
```

For scripts run in the context of the 3d view

```
space = context.space_data
```